# URI path template variable in JAX-RS

Tags: java, jax-rs, java-ee-6

In JavaEE documentation for JAX-RS webservices, I came across below statement:

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gilik.html

> If the URI path template variable cannot be cast to the specified
>   type, the JAX-RS runtime returns an HTTP 400 (“Bad Request”) error to
>   the client. If the @PathParam annotation cannot be cast to the
>   specified type, the JAX-RS runtime returns an HTTP 404 (“Not Found”)
>   error to the client.

```
@Path("/{username}")
public class MyResourceBean {
    ...
    @GET
    public String printUsername(@PathParam("username") String userId) {
        ...
    }
}
```

So if request has parameter "username" and if it cannot be type-casted to String then we get 400 error, then when we will get 404 error? I am new to web-services, please help me in understanding this.

Comment: your answer is in the link you have mentioned in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you had something like this instead:

```
@Path("/{userId}")
public class MyResourceBean {
    ...
    @GET
    public String printUsername(@PathParam("userId") int userId) {
        ...
    }
}
```

if the URI for your request is something like `/abc`, then you'd get a 400 because `abc` cannot be cast into an `int`. Now, if your request URI is '/', you'll get a 404 because there's no resource method associated with this URI.

Answer (score 1):

URIs are used as resource locators in this case. These rules match the requirements of the [HTTP specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-10.4).

Say JAX-RS exposes a single end-point matching on the URL `http://host/app/{someInt}` and `{someInt}` must be converted to an integer.

`http://host/app` does not match this so it returns 404 - not found.

`http://host/app/foo` matches the pattern but `foo` cannot be parsed to an integer so it returns 400 - bad request.